# I want to see a playback video of how this file was recorded, but I'm not sure how to watch it

Tags: unity-game-engine, record, playback, leap-motion, recorder

[recording](https://github.com/ultraleap/PlayRecorder/wiki/Recording-Setup)

I created service provider1 and service provider2 by multi-connecting two leap motions in Unity, which aims to record and replay hand motions.
We are doing it in recording setup, and after playing unity, we recorded it by pressing start recording and stop recording in the recording manager. However, this recording file was saved as a bytes.meta file and I want to see a playback video of how this file was recorded, but I'm not sure how to watch it.
I'll show you my current setup status as a picture.

Did I give the wrong record component to Service Provider 1 or 2 by any chance?

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBO7P.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHW3f.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjAL4.png)

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1VnW.png)

[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGdpY.png)

Or it seems that an empty file was created because the recording file was saved but the recording did not proceed.